# Working with Huge ArrayLists, Java OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space... use db?

Tags: java, database, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am having a memory problem that I completely understand the cause, but have no idea of a fix.  I have attempted to use the -Xmx2g tag and make the heap size larger, but there seems to be a hidden maximum. (if i used -Xmx512m I run out of space at the same time).

Assume I have 2 objects, an Area and a User.  My Area object holds an ArrayList of users:

```
public class Area {
      int numUsers;
      ArrayList<User> userList;
}
```

My User class holds an ArrayList of friends:

```
public class User {
      int userID;
      int numFriends;
      ArrayList<User> friends;
}
```

Just using a single Area, with 1 million users, and an average of 200 friends per user, I run out of heap space after about 680,000 Users are created.  Obviously if I lower the average number of friends/user to something closer to 100, I can store all of these objects in the heap.

What if I want to simulate 2 million Users in an area?  Or Hundreds of area's?

With this much data, is a database the only feasible way to do simulations using the information?

Comment: Yes, fitting a graph of this size into a single VM will get cramped. And no, there are a lot of ways other than a relational database that can hold and work with that much data. Which way is appropriate in your case depends on what you want to do with the data, and what your performance requirements are. Perpahs you can even create the data as you need it, avoiding the need to store it in its entirety?

Comment: The need to store it in its entirety is to eventually have multiple areas where some Users from area 1 can have a friend from area 42.  I suppose that storing it in memory wont be an option at that point.  At this point I just have to model this information.  The project calls for a realistic model of a social network.  Any structures i should research that you know of off hand?

Comment: Storing in memory can go very far. With current memory pricing at 100 Euro/8GByte most systems should not be disk based.

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, run w/ more than 2m on 64bit java but that will not solve the issue. Btw, for Area, you probably need id (not numUsers), the number of users/friends can be obtained from list.size()

Database/disk storage is a natural solution for representing a lot of object, you can alternatively use cluster of servers (beside running a huge box w/ 500+GB of memory)

To answer the question you have to supply some more data: what is the point of areas/ friend graphs/etc.

---

If you can code your own struct(ure) using ByteBuffer (which is probably not an easy task) you can go beyond the 32bit limitations by java.io.MappedByteBuffer, ScatteringByteChannel/GatheringByteChannel. However, it's not a rookie task at any rate but if you like programming, I'd advise to try your hand at.

I wish you good luck with your studies.

Comment: The number of users is actually passed into the area before the area is created.  This way when I create multiple areas with a different number of users I can do that. and each user will have their own id.

It is a school project for creating a realistic social network model.

Comment: There is a major downside in your graph model, it will lack any sort of realistic search/trace method if you rely on ArrayList. ArrayList requires O(n) for a simple contains operation. 
Few other notes: make sure you have only 1 instance of User per entity (I assume userID  defines an identity)

Comment: Call trimToSize() or make sure you use the constructor with initialCapacity to avoid excessive bytes into Object[].
_____
Bottom line: if you need large memory use 64bit OS

Comment: I know that the structure wont be effective when/if doing realistic simulations.  I was hoping to create the data in memory, then dump it into a better suited structure for doing simulations.  Even though that is beyond the scope of the project.

Comment: Creating it into an external form (since you need to expose your structure if you want to be used for real anyways) can do that. (Talking about MappedByteBuffer)

Comment: Unfortunately such a project will be like 95% managing the structure than doing anything really useful with :)

Comment: By external form you mean not in memory of the jvm right?  Wish I could just use all of my 4gb memory and it wouldnt even be a problem...

Answer (score 1):

Disk/database is only a solution if you can afford the factor 100.000 loss of random access performance (you might, there are lots of systems using a database). You can do much better with specialized data structures. Doing something special for fully connected subnetworks might save a lot of space.

Comment: Hhhmm... any links to the structures you are speaking of?  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Just add a FullyConnectedSubset class containing an ArrayList of Users, and make friends polymorphic?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I suppose you are talking about at the Friends level.  So a user with 100 friends would be connected to each of these friends, but that doesnt help me fit it into memory.  And it would be better to have Friend extend User?  Not sure how it will save space since right now a Friend is a user.   ArrayList<User> friends;

Comment: In a fully connected subset, each friend is connected to each other. Instead of storing that as a list of n-1 entries in n friends, create one special element: the FullyConnectedSubset, that you add to those n friends. Taking O(n) instead of O(n^2) space. You then have to create some accessors/iterators to hide this implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

To access more heap memory, move to a 64-bit OS and 64-bit JVM. If you are hitting problems with -Xmx512m, you are using 32-bit OS and/or JVM.

Comment: I am using Fedora c14 32 bit.  I have a max of 256?

Comment: The actual max depends on a number of complicated issues, such as memory mapping of libraries and how that fragments the memory space. You may be able to get a bit more usable memory headroom by making sure to launch java using java executable rather than the linked library (not sure what the library is called on linux).